# How to color clusters in scatter plot using an array?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn, scatter

I'm using `sklearn` `noisy_circles` [function](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_cluster_comparison.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-cluster-comparison-py) with 1500 points as they did in the link, to create 2 circles.
I have an array of points references, where every value is supposed to be a different cluster color:

```
nbrs_array = [ 88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88, 973,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
       973,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88, 984,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88, 992,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88, 972,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88, 992,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88, 984,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88, 972,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,  88,
        88,  88,  88,  88,  88]
```

There are 5 unique values in the array, hence there should be 5 different colors. But when I'm plotting it using:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.scatter(x,y, c=nbrs_array)
plt.show()
```

The output is [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the job:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize, to_hex
from sklearn import datasets


def get_colors(arr, cmap='viridis'):
    cmap = cm.get_cmap(cmap)
    n = len(np.unique(arr))
    colornorm = Normalize(vmin=1, vmax=n)
    hex_map = dict()
    for i, cl in enumerate(np.unique(arr)):
        hex_map[cl] = to_hex(cmap(colornorm(i + 1)))
    colors = list(map(lambda x: hex_map[x], arr))
    return colors


n_samples = 1500
data, _ = datasets.make_circles(n_samples=n_samples, factor=.5, noise=.05)
x, y = data[:, 0], data[:, 1]
nbrs_array = [...]

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.scatter(x, y, c=get_colors(nbrs_array))
plt.show()
```